# Test class values not updated in apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I am running a test class , where I am seeing that the value updated in test class is not getting reflected in the apex controller. I even tried to query in the test class and then call the apex method.

My test class :

```
testformulation[0].Ready_for_Submission__c = True;
update testformulation[0];
system.debug(testformulation[0].Ready_for_Submission__c); // this gives 'True'
Id WorkItemID = extn.getWorkItemId(testformulation[0].Id); //extn being the controller extension.
```

In Apex:

```
public Id getWorkItemId(Id targetObjectId)
    {
        Id retVal = null;

        formulation__c frm = [Select id,Ready_for_Submission__c from formulation__c where id=: targetObjectId];
        system.debug(frm.Ready_for_Submission__c); // this gives False
   }
```

Comment: Could there be something elsewhere is your could resetting it to false when doing the DML update?

Comment: Just curious, is the value of `Ready_for_Submission__c` truly `true` on the record you're querying in your apex? Not trying to insult your intelligence or anything, just wondering. Aside from something resetting the value like Eric suggested, that's the only thing I can figure.

Comment: I have checked it properly. it is true